# Using d:DesignInstance with CollectionViewSource

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, collectionviewsource, uwp

I am using `d:DesignInstance` to get design-time data in the designer. My model looks like this (simplified):

```
interface IModel {
  public ObservableCollection<IConversation> OpenConversations { get; }
}

enum ConversationType {
  Channel, IM
}

interface IConversation {
  public string Name { get; }
  public ConversationType ConversationType { get; }
}
```

Then I have a mock-model with a couple of entries in the `OpenConversations` property. This works great when used as the `ItemsSource` in my `ListView`. My simplified XAML view looks like this:

```
<Page d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=mocks:MockModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}">
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding OpenConversations}"/>
</Page>
```

The above example works as expected and I get design time data.

However now I would like to add grouping in my `ListView` using `CollectionViewSource` so I added the following to my XAML:

```
<Page.Resources>
  <CollectionViewSource x:Name="OpenConversations" IsSourceGrouped="True" />
</Page.Resources>
```

And changed the `ListView` to:

```
<ListView ItemSource="{StaticResource OpenConversations}" />
```

What I cannot really figure out though is how to get the design data into the
`CollectionViewSource`, I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<CollectionViewSource ... Source="{Binding OpenConversations}" />
```

According to the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780627.aspx I need to (in the code-behind) assign `CollectionViewSource.Source = from conversation in OpenConversations group by conversation.ConversationType into group select group`. But I cannot figure out how to do that using design-time data.

Comment: You can create the CollectionViewSource  in ViewModel instaead of codebehind if you are using MVVM pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First try to define how a group shoud look I mean title of group ,and many more

```
public class  Group<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public Group(string name,IEnumerable<T> items):base(items)
   { Name=name;
   }
  //more ...
}
```

This class is for more than static data ,it handles changing data. 
Now if you use MVVM model define in your viewmodel(home) a property  ListGroup (name how you desire) of type new ObservableCollection>
**PS not real code just mockup to give an ideea.**

```
 var s = from val in OpenConversations 
         group val by val.Conversationb into g 
         select new Group<IConversation>(g.Key.ToString(), g);
 GroupList = new ObservableCollection<Group<IConversation>>(s);
```

Now create a just like you did before a CollectionViewSource in resouce

```
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="cvs" IsSourceGrouped="True" Source="{Binding Source={StaticResource home},Path=GroupList}"/>

      <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Background="Salmon" Width="100" Height="100">
                    <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>              
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle >
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="LightGray"  >
                            <TextBlock Text='{Binding Name}' Foreground="Black" Margin="10"
                           Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>               
    </ListView>
```

See how a define GroupSyle you add more properties in here 
It work best for complete control i'm using it in w10 app.
Plus a has a partial design time helps(Shows only the list) :)) Not showing the header of group(GroupView)

Comment: //Not showing the header of group(GroupView) - true, have the same issue here.. any workarounds?